# xtreamer doesn't see Window 7 shares

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

Weird situation after reinstalling Windows 7 on my PC. Suddenly the xTreamer (media streamer) that's connected to the same LAN doesn't see shares by my PC.
Other PCs (and even a MacBook) on the same network can access these shares just fine. And the xTreamer is capable of seeing other shares in the network (e.g. by some other NAS server I have).

It can't be permissions/firewall because the Mac does connect to the shares... I'm stumped.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. [This](http://forum.xtreamer.net/Support/questions/344/) solution helped me:

> Click the Windows "Start" button in the lower left of your Desktop,
>   and in the "start search" area type "`regedit`" and press enter.
>
> 1. After a security prompt you should have the Registry Editor open.
> 2. Navigate to the following location in the registry editor.
>
> `MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\`
>
> 1. On the right side Double Click on `everyoneincludesanonymous` and in the window that pops up, change the value data from a 0 value to a 1
> 2. Double Click on `NoLmHash` and in the window that pops up, change the Value Data from a 1 value to a 0
> 3. Navigate to the following location in the registry editor
>
> `MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters`
>
> 1. Double Click on `restrictnullsessaccess` and change the 1 value to a 0
>
> NOTE: There is no need to "save" these changes, as you make changes to
>   the registry it is saved automatically.
>
> 2. Close the registry editor and restart the computer.
> 3. Once the PC restarts don't forget to update your available network shares on your xtreamer by using your remote to navigate the onscreen
>      menu to Refresh, once Refresh is selected press enter. The Windows
>      Vista shares should show on the xtreamer with no problems.

I couldn't remember doing that the first time a few years ago. Using old Sidewinder.
But it worked.

Comment: The articel recommends to change `EveryoneIncludeAanonymous` and `RestrictNullSessAccess`. This **will reduce the security** of windows 7. To avoid this changes, there should be a way to configure xtreamer to provide a regular logon to W7.